# primefaces 3.5 uploadfile not working, i using netbean 7.2.1

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

the problem is with file uploader from primefaces
web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

.xhtml

```
            </h:form>
               ...
            </h:form>
            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p:fileUpload value="#{contratosMB.fileContrato}" mode="simple"/>

                <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"  
                                 actionListener="#{contratosMB.upload}" update=":form2:formgen:growl"/>
            </h:form>
```

contratosMB.java

```
 public void upload() {  
        if(fileContrato != null) {  
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Se ha cargado correctamente el archivo: " + fileContrato.getFileName()); 
        }  
    }
```

I was read some question like this, but nothing was help me...
i was add commons-fileupload and commons-io to the project,
but dont work not go inside upload method, dont send exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it working creating and editing faces-config:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId> commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId> commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

but dont work full for me because form uploader is inside to other form...

```
   <h:form>
  ...
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  

            <p:messages showDetail="true"/>  

            <p:fileUpload value="#{contratosMB.fileContrato}" mode="simple"/>  

            <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"  
                             actionListener="#{contratosMB.upload}"/>  

        </h:form>  
    </h:form>
```

any body can tell me why??

Comment: thank you very much! mine wasn't working either. so I notice that `commons-fileupload` was missing in my project. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`actionListener="#{contratosMB.upload}"`

to

`action="#{contratosMB.upload}"` .

> Check this out :
>   [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Comment: that no chanche any thing...but starting glassfish send this:

Comment: Grave: Exception while visiting org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.class of size 12186
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.TypesImpl.getType(TypesImpl.java:78)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.ModelClassVisitor.visit(ModelClassVisitor.java:119)
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:363)

Comment: at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:171)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:133)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 0):

Nesting 'form' elements is illegal. Try to upload file in advanced mode and use FileUploadListener to access FileUploadEvent and data.